# How do I remove an element from a page by id using Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, edit, tampermonkey

I am trying to create a Tampermonkey script to remove an element on a webpage and I have no idea how to do it. I am trying to create something that finds the element by its id then deletes it, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

This is the element:

[image]

I've tried this:

```
var adSidebar = document.getElementById('user-list-toggle');
if (true) {
  adSidebar.parentNode.removeChild(adSidebar);
}
```

Comment: why `if (true)`? true is always true so why test if it is? anyway ... that should work as long as your tampermonkey script isn't running before that element exists of course ... also, you could just do `adSidebar.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a setTimeout so that the element has some time to load before it gets deleted.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         delete search - stack overflow
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    setTimeout(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById('search');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }, 1000); // add delay if needed 2000 = 2seconds
})();
```